# What is the name of this green plant with fat leaves with green color fruits?

Tags: species-identification

Location: South India,Metropolitan

Year: 2017

[image]

It look like ***Almond tree***, but small doubt not sure.

Comment: Looks like [Terminalia catappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminalia_catappa). Could you provide close-up of its fruits? Also; does the plant shed red leaves at late-autumn to winter?